# Mixpanel Swift- Logs are not displayed while debugging

Tags: ios, swift3, mixpanel

I am using Mixpanel for tracking. I have enabled debug logs for Mixpanel using the following codes which I am calling in `appDelegate` during `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` .

```
func configureMixpanel() {
        Mixpanel.initialize(token: mixPanelToken)
        Mixpanel.mainInstance().loggingEnabled = true
    }
```

But the logs are not being displayed.